# Как в innerHTML обработать цикл и вывести результат?

Tags: javascript, foreach

Можно решить такое именно конкретно внутри `innerHTML` и не запределами этой конструкции?

```js
let accounts = {
 1: { name: 'Sergey' },
 2: { name: 'Irina' },
};

Object.values(accounts).forEach(e => console.log(e));

document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = `<div>
  ${Object.values(accounts).forEach(e => `<div>${e.name}</div>`)}
</div>`;
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо сделать чуть по-другому:

Сделать **где-либо в другом месте цикл**, в котором в одну единственную переменную собрать html конкатенацией, а затем этот html впихнуть в `innerHTML`

---

Если так сильно хочется, то можно сделать через `map` или `reduce`, которые в качестве результата что-то возвращают в итоге (в отличие от forEach). Но я не советую так писать код, потому что это не читаемо

```
${Object.values(accounts).map(e => `<div>${e.name}</div>`).join('')}
```

делать так нечитаемо

Comment: Это я знаю, просто думал может какой то хак есть или еще как то. А через callback функцию можно такое сделать? незнаю только как такое пишется внутри ковычек

Comment: Дописал ответ. Но моё мнение - надо писать читаемо. Можно тот же  результат map сложить в переменную хотя бы и вставить эту переменную в итоговую строку

Comment: Спасибо, я только что прямо сейчас еще узнал про reduce, почти тоже самое `${Object.values(accounts).reduce((p, c) => p + `<div>${c.name}</div>`, '')}` Про читаемость понимаю, но кроме меня его врядли кто будет читать))

Comment: @Stase22 поверьте, через полгода если посмотрите на код, скажете - что за фигня, ничего не понятно))  Это происходит очень часто)  Про reduce тоже упомянул кста,